# WPF - Assign Enum Value To Prism's RegionName Directly

Tags: wpf, xaml, refactoring, prism, desktop-application

I am using Prism, this is a chunk of `.xaml` code of the main window

```xml
<mah:MetroWindow
    x:Class="ProjectName.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/">
        
    <ContentControl
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="CenterRegion" />
        
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

I have grouped all regions' names in an Enum `UiRegion`, And now, I want to rename some of the values in `UiRegion`, but renaming will not affect the strings in `.xaml`! Hence, I have to change them manually.. So I've tried to change the `.xaml` code to something like this

```xml
<ContentControl
    prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static model:UiRegion.CenterRegion}" />
```

But it gives a runtime error at `InitializeComponent();`

> 'CenterRegion' is not a valid value for property 'RegionName'.

**My Question is**: Is there a way to fix this? and if not, is there another way to update `.xaml` code when renaming `UiRegion` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was working on deriving the RegionManager to add a property of type UiRegion and pass the value of x:Static it to the original property.

It's better to create a markup extension:

```cs
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(string))]
    public class UiRegionExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public UiRegion UiRegion { get; set; }

        public UiRegionExtension(UiRegion uiRegion)
        {
            UiRegion = uiRegion;
        }

        public UiRegionExtension() { }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return UiRegion.ToString();
        }
    }
```

```xml
<ContentControl
    prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{m_ext:UiRegion CenterRegion}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Prism, but I will assume that the RegionName property is of type String. But you want to assign an Enum value to a string. x:Static (just like StaticResource and DynamicResource) does not perform type conversion. To convert, you need to use Binding.
I think the assignment will happen without error if done like this:

```xml
<ContentControl
    prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{Binding Source={x:Static model:UiRegion.CenterRegion}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`class`es do work, too:

code:

```
public static class RegionNames
{
    public const string MAIN_REGION = "mainregion";
    public const string DETAILS_REGION = "someotherfunnyidentifier";
}
```

xaml:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:RegionNames.MAIN_REGION}" />
```